# How to 'return' out of a parent function from it's child?

Tags: javascript, function

I frequently use a verifyInput function inside my projects to ensure I get a valid input from users. Now and again I find myself wishing that I could exit my parent function from my verifyInput. verifyInput is usually given a `prompt()` function. Prompts, have cancel keys. I'd like to exit my nested expression if cancel is clicked. How would I do this?

```
function verifyInput(foo, value){
    const input = foo();
    if (!isNaN(input) && !input || input === null || input === undefined){
        if(input === null){
            /*The input is null, because they hit the cancel button. I should exit myLoop here.*/
        } else {
            alert("Not valid.");
        }
        return verifyInput(foo,value);
    } else {
        if(value && input.search(value) < 0){
            alert("'"+[input]+"' is not a valid input.");
            return verifyInput(foo,value);
        }else{
            return input;
        }
    }
}

function myFunc(){
    var myInput = verifyInput( () => prompt("What is your input?"));
    alert(myInput);
    return myFunc();
}
myFunc();
```

Comment: Can you post a complete example? There's no loop in this code.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn No problem, consider it done!

Comment: @LucasCosta I'm confused. I don't know the answer, so I can't answer it myself.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just return `true/false` from `verifyInput` to tell `myLoop` if it should make the recursive call? I assume that's the "loop" you're talking about.

Comment: @squint In hindsight my question was very poorly worded. I've fixed it up to make it more clear. `verifyInput(arg)` returns `arg` if `arg` is a valid input.

Comment: @Ucenna Well, you're not looping (that's recursion) and `null` is an invalid value so why not just return `null` then `myLoop` checks if the result is `null`?

Comment: @MikeC It's mostly for typing efficiency. `test = verifyInput(x)` is a lot shorter than `test = verifyInput(x); if(test === null){return;};`. Also, it's something that I've wanted to do in other scenarios. If I there is a way to do it, and I know how to do it; then I'll have more options and more powerful code. In theory anyway.

Comment: @all You're right this is not a loop, I'll adjust everything to refect that.

Comment: @Ucenna There's only 3 ways to exit a function: run the function to completion, `return` from it, or throw an error. Error handling is expensive and a bad way of organizing well-behaved code so you're left with running to completion or `return`ing. Since you want to exit early, that leaves you with `return`ing. So... You're stuck.

Comment: @MikeC Very well. I was worried that was the case. I'll just have to adjust my coding habits. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to directly stop the execution of the caller (`myLoop`) directly from `verifyInput` unless you throw an exception.

As others said, you could check the return value from `myLoop` to stop it conditionally.

But maybe a cleaner solution would be using a callback for that, which would only be called if the input is not `"exit"`. This callback would be responsible for getting the input if it's valid and calling `myFunc` again to continue the loop. Example:

```
function verifyInput(prompter, callback) {
  var value = prompter()

  if (value === "exit") {
    return // don't proceed with the callback if `value` is "exit"
  }

  if (invalid(value)) { // function to be implemented
    alert("invalid")
    return verifyInput(prompter, callback)
  }

  callback(value)
}

function myFunc() {
  var prompter = () => prompt("What is your input?")
  verifyInput(prompter, (value) => {
    console.log(value) // logs the input
    myFunc()
  })
}

myFunc()
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/guisehn/r1Lwxkhp/

Comment: That's interesting. I've been meaning to take a look at the callback function, because I never fully understood it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Actually, `callback` is not a special keyword or anything like that, it's just the name I gave to the argument of the function. The idea here is to receive a function as the 2nd argument of `verifyInput` and then call it inside `verifyInput` only if a specific condition if met.

Comment: ...I knew that... Or I would've had I paid more attention to your argument names... I could've sworn I'd seen `callback` used in another context. Guess not. Thanks!